Ubuntu 22.04 Network Problem
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, but I am having problems with the internet. At first, I can use the internet easily, but sometimes the internet becomes unusable and I can fix it by turning the computer's internet off and on, but this is not a permanent solution.

You'll need to update the question with more details to get the best chance of a fix. Have you tried anything at all? Have a read through this: https://www.jamesparker.dev/how-do-i-troubleshoot-network-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu/

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Troubleshoot your problem by running an Ubuntu USB live session. It could be either a alphanumerical problem or a problem with your ISP.
